# I am getting insane lag in my game and I know why but I am usure on how to fix it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In my game I spawn in zombies that are meant to chase the player when the player gets in the radius. The following code is what does that but my problem is that there are over 100 zombies meaning that this script is running over 100 times each frame which causes insane lag. I am getting around 1.7FPS but when I commented out the script my FPS shot up to 40 FPS. Is there another way to run this function?

(Sorry if it is bad/messy code I am a noob)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ZK_attack : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.5f;
    public float InRadius = 4.0f;
    public float AttackRange = 1.0f;    
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;

        transform.LookAt(Player);

        
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= InRadius)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("inRadius", true);

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= AttackRange)
            {
                anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", true);


            }

        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= InRadius)
        {
            anim.SetBool("inRadius", false);
        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= AttackRange)
        {
            anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", false);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not expecting votes for this, but it doesn't really fit in a comment.)

Just to build on @AKX's answer a bit, try this. The only difference is moving the `GameObject.Find` call, which can be very costly, out of the `Update`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ZK_attack : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.5f;
    public float InRadius = 4.0f;
    public float AttackRange = 1.0f;    
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    /// Shamelessly copied from @AKX's answer. 
    void Update() 
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);

        float dstSqr = (Player.Position - transform.Position).sqrMagnitude;
        bool inRadius = (dstSqr <= InRadius * InRadius);
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);
        anim.SetBool("inRadius", inRadius);
        anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", inAttackRange);
        if (inRadius)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked very well I was able to get 25 FPS with this

Comment: @Jeff glad it helped. Don't forget to upvote AKX's answer.

Comment: @Jeff note that if you remove & recreate "Player" while the game is running, you'd need to reassign `.Player` to the new object. Might not be an issue, but something to keep in the back of your mind. (If you recreate the zombies after the player is recreated, it won't be an issue.)

Answer (score 2):

- The distance computation is relatively heavy -- you should only do it once.
- In addition, due to distance computation requiring a square root, you can here use `sqrMagnitude`.
- Then, you can simplify the if/else logic.

```
    void Update()
    {
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;

        transform.LookAt(Player);

        float dstSqr = (Player.Position - transform.Position).sqrMagnitude;
        bool inRadius = (dstSqr <= InRadius * InRadius);
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);
        anim.SetBool("inRadius", inRadius);
        anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", inAttackRange);
        if (inRadius)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Good answer.

Comment: I got the error: 'Vector3' does not contain a definition for 'DistanceSquared'. Is there anything I should add?

Comment: @Jeff use `(Player.Position-transform.Position).sqrMagnitude;` See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html

Comment: @Jeff Also, this should *probably* be done in `FixedUpdate`, not `Update`.

Comment: @3Dave sorry I am an idiot but where in the script should I put (Player.Position-transform.Position).sqrMagnitude;

Comment: @Jeff This answer has been updated. `DistanceSquared` is available in just about every other `Vector3` implementation. Unity just decided to do it this way instead.

Comment: @Jeff not to turn this into a discussion on another user's answer, but I'd have a look at `RigidBody` as well. The Unity physics engine is very good. You'll already need to use it for collision detection, among other things. Doing that now, before things get too complicated, will make your life easier in the future.

Comment: @3Dave When I tried this it barely made a difference, I went from 1.7 FPS to 1.8 FPS so maybe there is something wrong or I did something wrong but I copied it word for word.

Comment: @Jeff Then it's time to learn how the profiler works, and identify the slow parts.

Comment: @Jeff Move the `Player = GameObject.Find(...` to `Start()`. Searching by a string within a complex scene is going to very costly.